# How to open TCP port in Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: ubuntu, port

How to open TCP port in Ubuntu 10.10 ?

Comment: Belongs either on http://superuser.com or http://askubuntu.com.

Comment: For what do you want to open the port? To host a service? to use for outgoing traffic? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 16):

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport (port number) -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: No,no. I need to open port in system, for application like torrent client or apache server.

Comment: @Romka no no, thats not how you ask a question, more info needed, this answer is correct

Answer (score 5):

Shooting in the darkness:

```
sudo ufw allow 80
```

Now there is a rule in your ubuntu firewall allowing external access to your 80 port. If you want more specific rule see `man ufw`. If you are on non-routable IP address you have to forward port in your router. If you provide more context to your question, then I can adjust this answer.

Comment: This doesn't work under Ubuntu 12.10... `nmap localhost -p80` still displays `CLOSED`

Comment: `sudo ufw enable` would be required first on a default Ubuntu install, since ufw is disabled by default.

Answer (score 3):

Your question needs a lot more detail:

- What do you mean by "open a port"? Do you want to do it in a program? Just run a program?
- What is your network configuration? LAN structure, Internet uplink, OSes involved, which router/switch...
- Do you have any firewalls / NAT in place? On your system, elsewhere in the network?

That said, if you have the "typical" home setup (one or more computers hooked up to a combined switch/router with Internet uplink via DSL or cable): Typically the switch/router/modem combo has a built-in firewall. You'll probably need to open a port there. Usually these devices have a web interface for configuration, look into your manuals.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/): The very basic way to do that (via Netcat) is:

```
nc -l <port_number>
```

Example:

```
nc -l 12569
```